# Video play VLC player only in Android(Video Recording using FFmpeg)

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to **record video from url**, its fine I can record video from my url but **the problem is the recorded video only play VLC player**, can't play no other video players. I think it is the problem of video encoding. my url is **http://192.168.1.1:8080/?action=stream** . So I have getting **mpeg** encoded frames from this url. I used different ffmpeg command but these are not worked properly. These are the command I used.

```
"ffmpeg -i "+URL+" -codec:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart "+toFile;

"ffmepg -i "+URL+" -acodec libfaac -ab 96k -vcodec libx264 -vpre slower -vpre main -level 21 -refs 2 -b 345k -bt 345k -threads 0 -s 640×360 "+toFile;
```

So anyone knows how to fix these problem please help me...

Comment: http://192.168.1.1:8080/?action=stream  - really? a local network? -  I am on a different local network!!! Add your external IP and do a port forwarding!

Comment: yes the video stream from one camera device.

Comment: We can't access your PC at  192.168.1.1:8080, because it will point to our router, not yours! https://www.h3xed.com/web-and-internet/whats-the-difference-between-external-and-local-ip-addresses

Comment: I can stream and record video from this URL. the problem is after recording, the recorded video only play in VLC player.